# Contesting a rejected edit - This edit deviates from the original intent of the post

Tags: support, edits, rejected-edits

I am trying to understand the reasons for rejecting [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14453276)

I do understand that its not a substantial change, but the answer had missing variables, which made it wrong, and I thought its best to have a correct answer.

However, I also don't understand the rejection reasons.

> This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits
>   that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of
>   the post's owner.

How did the edit deviate from the answer? and how do you the know the original intent if you are not the author, especially that the edit fixed using a self reference instead of the input in a compare method that takes two parameters.

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read,
>   easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either
>   completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

Isn't making the answer correct a part of making it more accurate?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe this was a good edit, which was incorrectly rejected. Before the edit, the code doesn't even compile. As mentioned [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260246/4751173), you may edit code in answers to

> - Fix syntax errors and typos

---

However, you could have made a more descriptive edit summary, because

> fix variables

might be interpreted as 'the variable names used by the OP don't comply to my own convention, so I fix them'. Instead, something like

> The code written by the author doesn't compile, because he's using the wrong variable names. I fixed them.

would clearly specify your intentions and increase the chance of approval. Still, reviewers are <s>robo</s> humans and can make mistakes.

Comment: the question remains if a code edit is warranted. Specially because after the edit that code would still not compile. Maybe a down vote and comment would have been better.

Comment: *Specially because after the edit that code would still not compile.* am I missing something?

Comment: I thought  the fields or properties used, Episode and Season are not defined. The struct is incomplete.

Comment: Yeah, I assumed those are defined in the context. Otherwise, the OP's code and the code in the [great answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5672992/4751173) don't compile as well.

Comment: that is true, hence my comment. It depends a bit on what you consider *fixed*. This doesn't feel like just a syntax error or a typo.

Comment: To me, it feels like an author who copy/pasted (with attribution) some code from another answer, modified it and didn't bother to check if it compiled or not.

Comment: @rene the missing context is implied, thats why i didn't fix it, however not compiling is only part of the edit, the main reason is that the method didn't use the input variable, and yes a comment helps, but why wait for a fix when i can do right away